# React useContext's Undefined Return Value

Tags: reactjs, jsx, react-context

I'm new to react and I'm facing a problem regarding `useContext`.

I want to connect to some API and get some data from there, and store it in a context.

So, here is the `MovieContextProvider.jsx` file that is responsible for this:

```
import React, { useState, createContext, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';


const MovieContext = createContext();

const URL = "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie?sort_by=popularity.desc&api_key=9813ce01a72ca1bd2ae25f091898b1c7";

function MovieContextProvider({ children }) {

    const [movieData, setMovieData] = useState();

    useEffect(() => {

        axios.get(URL)
            .then((response) => setMovieData(response.data.results))
            .catch((error) => console.log(error));

    }, []);


    return (

        <MovieContext.Provider value={movieData}>
            {children}
        </MovieContext.Provider>

    );
}

export default MovieContextProvider;
```

Now, I'm using this context in another file `Movies.jsx`

```
import React from 'react';
//import MovieCard from '../Components/MovieCard';

import { useContext } from 'react';

import MovieContext from '../Contexts/MovieContextProvider';

function Movies() {

    const movieData = useContext(MovieContext);

    console.log(movieData); //Here I'm checking firstly if the data
                           //received properly from the context

    return (

        <div>

            Movies...
            
        </div>
    );
}

export default Movies;
```

Lastly, this is my `App.js` file

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';

import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import NavBar from './Components/NavBar';
import Home from './Components/Home';
import AboutUs from './Components/AboutUs';
import Movies from './Components/Movies';
import MovieContextProvider from './Contexts/MovieContextProvider';


function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">

      <MovieContextProvider>
        <BrowserRouter>
          <NavBar></NavBar>

          <Routes>
            <Route path='/Movies' element={<Movies></Movies>}></Route>

            <Route path="/Home" element={<Home></Home>}></Route>

            <Route path="/AboutUs" element={<AboutUs></AboutUs>}></Route>

          </Routes>
        
        </BrowserRouter>
        
      </MovieContextProvider>
      


    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

The problem now is that when I log the `movieData` inside the `Movies.jsx` file its value is *undefined*. Even though, when I log it inside the `MovieContextProvider.jsx` it appears as expected.

So, do I'm using `useContext(context)` in a wrong way? I have done many research online and I have found some articles here on Stack Overflow, but I have failed to solve the problem.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use react hook like this.

Add hook function to MovieContextProvider.jsx

```
export const useMovieContext = () => useContext(MovieContext)
```

Then, use useMovieContext function instead of useContext(MovieContext) in Movies.jsx

```
const movieData = useMovieContext()

useEffect(() => {
    console.log(movieData);
}, [movieData])
```

Finally, you can get axios result in Movies.jsx